# How to use a self defined Distance Metric in Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, distance, knn

I have written the code to compute distance between two rows of input matrices and plan on running KNeighborsClassifier on it.
How do I use a different distance metric in Sklearn KNeighborsClassifier?

*For example:*

```
def distanceMetric(a, b):
    distance = <some distance>
    return distance
```

Also which Classifiers offer the ability to define a new distance function?

Comment: have you looked at the API?  http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics

Comment: @WildCard, I think you have misunderstood, I don't want to use one of the pre-built metrics but want to use my own.

Answer (score 2):

Sklearn has a bunch of built in distance metrics. But if you would like to use your own you do the following:

```
NearestNeighbors(metric='pyfunc', func=distanceMetric)
```

Check out the [distance metric page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) in sklearn for a full list of options.

Comment: I already know how to use it on a clustering algorithm but what I need is for a classification algorithm

Comment: @NinadT Are you asking how to do this in KNearestNeighbors() or in any classification in general?